# Iterating through couchbase keys without a view

Tags: couchbase

In couchbase, I was wondering if there was a way - WITHOUT using a view - to iterate through database keys. The admin interface appears to do this, but maybe its doing something special. What I'd like to is make a call like this to retrieve an array of keys:

$result = $cb->get("KEY_ALBERT", "KEY_FRED");
having the result be an array [KEY_ALEX, KEY_BOB, KEY_DOGBERT]

Again, I don't want to use a view unless there's no alternative. Doesn't look like its possible, but since the "view documents" in the admin appears to do this, I thought i'd double-check. I'm using the php interface if that matters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know about how couchbase admin works, but there are two options. First option is to store your docs as linked list, one doc have property (key) that points to another doc.

```
docs = [
  {
     id: "doc_C",
     data: "somedata",
     prev: "doc_B",
     next: "doc_D"
  },
  {
     id: "doc_D",
     data: "somedata",
     prev: "doc_C",
     next: "doc_E"
  }
]
```

The second approach is to use sequential id. You should have one doc that contain sequence and increment it on each add. It would be something like this:

```
docs = [
  {
     id: "doc_1",
     data: "somedata"
  },
  {
     id: "doc_2",
     data: "somedata"
  }    
  ...
]
```

In this way you can do "range requests". To do this you form array of keys on server side:
`[doc_1, doc_2 .... doc_N]`and execute multiget query. Here is also a [link to another example](http://tugdualgrall.blogspot.com/2012/11/building-chat-application-using-nodejs.html#highlighter_664683)

Comment: Thanks, I'm aware of those two options. unfortunately neither of those is what i'm really looking for. I guess I'm mostly looking for clarification that there is no api that i'm missing that allows for key range retrieval. If no other answers come in i'll accept your answer as it is a solution .. just not the one i want:)

Comment: Then there are no other option but using views, I think. Also I think that in admin interface they use just list of all keys with `skip` and `limit` to display those docs. You can also try to ask on [couchbase forums](http://www.couchbase.com/forums/).

Comment: ya, i was just being certain i wasn't missing anything. i'm going to accept this answer as it appears to be the only one. i'll post the question in the couchbase forums just in case. i know there are some difference in the various apis ... i was hoping it was a feature they just didn't include in the php api for some reason:)

Answer (score 4):

Based on your comments, the only way is to create a simple view that emit only the id as par of the key:

```
function(doc, meta) {
  emit( meta.id );
}
```

With this view you will be able to create query with the various options you need :
 - pagination, range, ...

Note: you talk about the Administration Console, the console use an "internal view" that is similar to what I have written above (but not optimized)

Answer (score 0):

The couchbase PHP sdk does support multiget requests.  For a list of keys it will return an array of documents.

`getMulti(array $ids, array $cas, int $flags) : array`

http://www.couchbase.com/autodocs/couchbase-php-client-1.1.5/classes/Couchbase.html#method_getMulti